# Discriminant is zero iff $f\in K[X]$ has repeated roots

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, symmetric-polynomials

I have to prove the statement in the title. Proving from right to left is easy. Now from left to right: $D=(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)^2(\alpha_1-\alpha_3)^2\cdots(\alpha_{n-1}-\alpha_n)^2$ where $\alpha_i$ are the roots of $f$ in the splitting field. Now $D=0$ implies that somewhere in the product we have a zero, so for some $i$ and $j$ we have that $\alpha_i=\alpha_j$. This $\alpha_i$ doesn't have to be in $K$. So we can't conclude deg(gcd($f,f'$))>0.From here I don't know what to do. Can someone give the proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$ are not in $K$, they are in
a algebraic closure $\bar{K}$ of $K$. So ${\sf gcd}_{\bar{K}}(f,f')$ is
nonconstant. But the euclidean algorithm shows that 
${\sf gcd}_{\bar{K}}(f,f')={\sf gcd}_{K}(f,f')$, so you are done.

Comment: can you explain why $\text{gcd}_{\overline{K}}(f,f')=\text{gcd}_{K}}(f,f')$? I don't see it immediately

Comment: @Badshah The euclidean algorithm produces the same computations over any field, $K$ or any field above $K$. The sequence in that algorithm is therefore made of polynomials in $K[X]$. This shows that the gcd in any field above $K$ is in fact in $K[X]$.

Comment: To give more detail to Ewan's excellent answer: the Euclidean algorithm takes a pair of polynomials $(u,v)$, sorts them so that w.l.o.g. the degree of $u$ is larger than or equal to the degree of $v$, and then replaces $(u,v)$ with $(v,r)$, where $r$ is the remainder of $u$ divided by $b$.  Repeat until $r=0$.  Then $v$ is the gcd.  Now by induction you can prove that if $u$ and $v$ have coefficients in $K$, then so will their g.c.d.